# How to combine audio and output with python

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg, moviepy

This question was asked a few times a couple of years ago, but none of the solutions seem to work.

This code creates a video `output.mp4` which is the same as `video.mp4`, but it doesn't have any sound from `audio.mp3` even when `video.mp4` has sound in the first place.

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

audio = mp.AudioFileClip("audio_output/audio.mp3")
video1 = mp.VideoFileClip("video.mp4")
final = video1.set_audio(audio)

final.write_videofile("output.mp4")
```

If anyone knows of alternative methods without using moviepy please let me know! (Or if you know why this isn't working)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct for replacing the audio of the video with the provided audio file using `moviepy`. However, there can be various reasons why it might not work, such as incompatible audio formats or issues within the `moviepy` library itself.

Here's how you can replace the audio of a video using `ffmpeg` as another method:

```bash
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio_output/audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4
```